# how to compile an Android project using com.sun.webkit

Tags: android, gradle

The error I hit is this one:

```
Task :lib:compileJava FAILED
....java:8: error: package com.sun.webkit.dom does not exist
import com.sun.webkit.dom.ElementImpl;
                     ^
```

It seems to be missing a dependency. MIght be this one?

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.webkit/webview-deps/1.3.2

That web page suggested a portion to be added to build.gradle:

```
compile group: 'com.sun.webkit', name: 'webview-deps', version: '1.3.2', ext: 'pom'
```

But it merely added the following warning without any effect on the said error:

```
WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: 
http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
```

I improvised this in build.gralde without any effect either, not even generating additional output like the above warning.

```
implementation 'com.sun.webkit:webview-deps:1.3.2'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround - use Oracle JDE 8u191 instead of the default openJDK. It's still confusing though, since there is absolutely no document to be found with Google about where com.sun.webkit.dom.ElementImpl is from, or where com.sun.webkit.dom is from. The only clue by Google would be the existence of standalone jar files covering those:

https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.openjfx/javafx-web/11/source-code

Which I could not find ways to use in openJDK.